# Custom Process Library Blocks in AnyLogic

Tags: java, anylogic

it is possible in a **wait block** to change the inside queue behaviour?

Instead that the element saves agents in a standard queue it save in a HashMap so the code in the event handlers can performs search with a lower code complexity?

The solution that I have found is to slide, with an iterator, all the elements inside the queue but with a HashMap is much quicker to find if a particular agent is present or not. I wouldn't place global HashMap variables in the **onStartup** event handler of the main agent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood what I said on the other question. You do not change the queue behavior of the **Wait** block. You simply add a Collection of type HashMap (or LinkedHashMap) to assist you in information management. That Collection will have the key ID and the object Agent because searching a  structure is more efficient than searching the Anylogic **Wait** Process Modelling Library element.

If you do not want to create a collection for each **Wait** block, what you can do is create a custom element using a new Agent.

For that you create a new Agent type and in that Agent you place an **In Port** and an **Out Port** as entering and exiting points. Than you place a **Wait** block and a collection of type HashMap to store info. You will have to also create some parameters to input information (other Departments in which you need to check if the order is already present, etc.). This is more advanced Anylogic utilization and perhaps confuse to the beginner so I wouldn't recommend stepping into it without getting familiar with Anylogic.

Comment: There some material (PDF/tutorial/book) to learn on how create custom and reusable elements?

Comment: Unfortunately, to my knowledge, there are not yet. Anylogic is very young in terms of documentation and only tutorials and PDFs on basic stuff are available. However, due to the great value of the software I believe more content will be produced in a near future. Actually, I'll spend some time doing something like that but it will take some time to be good!

Comment: Thanks. I hope that AnyLogic will produce some tutorial on advanced topics like that :)